# exclude base class realm in serializing the class

Tags: c#, xamarin, realm

I have a class `Contact` which is derived from `Realm` in `Xamarin.Forms` now when i am trying to serialize it using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` to send data to server.

But the issue is , it is converting all its base class properties `Realm` to JSON as well. I do not have any control on realm class as its a third party class.

so how can i ignore the entire `Realm` class from my model.

`Contact` model

```
public class Contact : RealmObject
    {
        public string birthdate { set; get; }
        public string city { set; get; }
        [PrimaryKey]
        public string contactId { set; get; }
        public string country { set; get; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `JsonObject` attribute on you class, and change the serialization of properties to opt-in:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Contact : RealmObject
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string birthdate { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string city { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string contactId { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string country { set; get; }
}
```

This way only properties with `JsonProperty` attribute will be serialized.

Note: you may also use `DataContract` instead of `JsonObject` and `DataMember` instead of `JsonProperty`. They work in the same way with Json.NET.

## Alternative using a custom `ContractResolver`

You can achieve the same result using a custom `ContractResolver` (writing a little more code):

```
public class MyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public new static readonly MyContractResolver Instance = new MyContractResolver();

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (property.DeclaringType == typeof(RealmObject))
        {
            property.ShouldSerialize = o => false;
        }

        return property;
    }
}
```

Remember to assign it to the serializer when serializing:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
      contact,
      Formatting.Indented,
      new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = MyContractResolver.Instance });
```

Comment: Do you have any example to use `DataContract` wherein i can simple consider Contact class rather than tagging each field

Comment: With opt-in serialization you can't. You must decorate single properties if you cannot access to the base class

Comment: @Hunt Added an alternative using a custom ContractResolver